# What's wrong with this htaccess entry?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

Why isn't this working?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/filter/([A-Za-z0-9])*$ /index.php?filter=$1
```

Trying to get this:
http://www.site.com/filter/whatever-is-here

loading this:
http://www.site.com/filter/index.php?filter=whatever-is-here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/filter/([A-Za-z0-9]*)$ /index.php?filter=$1
```

You misplaced the `*`, it needs to be on the character class.

Also, if you want to have `things-with-dashes`, then you would need to use `[-A-Za-z0-9]` as your character class

Comment: Changed to this ``RewriteRule ^/filter/([-A-Za-z0-9]*)$ /index.php?filter=$1`` but still not working.. strange

Comment: What is the full path you are trying to load?

Comment: Try doing `RewriteRule ^filter/([-A-Za-z0-9]*)$` (maybe the slash is messing it up)